# Returning an Array incorrectly, overwriting all with the last item

Tags: java, arrays, return

I've seen some similar post but not the same issue I'm having. What I'm trying to do is calling a function that shows the name of the files numbered as

```
1- File1.txt,
2- File2.txt
..
```

This works as expected. The problem is that I need to return the path of those files in another Array. When I `System.out.print(arrayRutasFicheros[j])` inside `for`, it shows all paths correctly. But when I try to access `arrayRutasFicheros[j]` from other functions. It just overwrites all the paths and just shows the last one.

```
public static String[] listarArchivos() throws IOException{

    File[] listadoDeFiles = documento.listFiles();
    File[] arrayFicheros = null;
    String[] arrayRutasFicheros = null;

    if(documento.exists() ) {

        for (int k=0; k< listadoDeFiles.length ;k++) {

            File ficheroRuta = listadoDeFiles[k];

            File fichero = new File(documento.getPath() + sep+ ficheroRuta.getName());

            if(fichero.isFile()==true) {

                arrayFicheros =new File[] {fichero};

                System.out.println( k + " - " + ficheroRuta.getName());

                for(int j= 0; j<arrayFicheros.length; j++) {

                    arrayRutasFicheros =  new String[] {arrayFicheros[j].getPath()};

                    //here it works and it display all the path
                    System.out.println(arrayRutasFicheros[j]);
                }   

            }   
        }       
    }

    return arrayRutasFicheros;
}

public static muestraUnArchivo() throws IOException {

    String [] Fichero =listarArchivos();

    for(int k=0; k<Fichero.length; k++) {

    //here just the last one
    System.out.print(Fichero[k]);       
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
-E:\Eclipse\Files\File1.txt   
-E:\Eclipse\Files\File2.txt  
-E:\Eclipse\Files\File3.txt
```

Output:

```
-E:\Eclipse\Files\File3.txt
```

Comment: Just step through your code (or put in some logging). You set `arrayRutasFicheros` on every `j` iteration.

Comment: `arrayRutasFicheros =  new String[] {arrayFicheros[j].getPath()};` creates an array with one entry (the `arrayFicheros[j]` entry). Thus your last iteration sets it to the last element in `arrayFicheros` - if you wanted to copy the `arrayFicheros` paths you should allocate an `arrayRutasFicheros` of the same size as `arrayFicheros` **before** the loop.

Comment: Of course `arrayFicheros` is also only one element. Perhaps you wanted a `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is recreated on every iteration of the loop, which is also on an array of length `1`. You need a dynamic structure to store the string paths, because you don't know ahead of time how many there are. Also, you don't need to keep creating single element arrays; use a `List<String>`. Something like,

```
public static String[] listarArchivos() throws IOException {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    if (documento.exists()) {
        File[] listadoDeFiles = documento.listFiles();
        for (File ficheroRuta : listadoDeFiles) {
            File fichero = new File(documento.getPath() 
                    + sep + ficheroRuta.getName());
            if (fichero.isFile()) {
                al.add(fichero.getPath());
            }
        }
    }

    return al.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your fast answers, you helped a lot!!! Indeed , The problem is that I was overwriting the variable on every iteration. Creating a List<String> solved it!

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are not only unnecessary but also causing the issue which you are facing. The line, `arrayRutasFicheros =  new String[] {arrayFicheros[j].getPath()};` is resetting `arrayRutasFicheros` for each value of `k` and therefore you will get only the value assigned to it at the the last value of `k`.

```
if(fichero.isFile()==true) {

    arrayFicheros =new File[] {fichero};

    System.out.println( k + " - " + ficheroRuta.getName());

    for(int j= 0; j<arrayFicheros.length; j++) {

        arrayRutasFicheros =  new String[] {arrayFicheros[j].getPath()};

        //here it works and it display all the path
        System.out.println(arrayRutasFicheros[j]);
    }   

}
```

Replace the above lines with the following code:

```
if(fichero.isFile()) {
    arrayRutasFicheros[k] =  fichero.getPath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line set the last value when the for ends the iteration.

I hope you will understand the logic.

```
arrayRutasFicheros =  new String[] {arrayFicheros[j].getPath()};
```

Please let me know if you have any confusion.

Happy coding.

Comment: It may take me longer than others, I'm a completly noob after all :P Thanks for your answers!